# Trying to make a "Live event" in unity C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

there I am trying to make a sort of "Live event" in unity example being of course Fortnite live events.

In other scripting languages, I could just check to see if the "UNIX" time thing is a certain time and from there can create a sort of timer leading up to the time. I was wondering the best way to go about making a function or something execute when the time and date are on a chosen time/date. And how to make a sort of timer with this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity has a lot of timing functions.

There are several ways to implement:

1. Manual timing:

   ```
   float persistTime = 10f
   float startTime = Time.time;
   if(Time.time - startTime > persistTime)
   {
      Debug.Log("Time out");
    }

   float curTime = 0;
   curTime += Time.deltaTime;
   if(curTime > persistTime)
   {
        Debug.Log("Time out");
   }
   ```
2. Coroutines:

   ```
   private float persistTime = 10f;
   IEnumerator DelayFunc()
   {
     yield return persistTime;
      Debug.Log("Time out");
   }

   private void Start()
   {
       StartCoroutine(DelayFunc());
   }
   ```
3. Invoke callback:

   ```
   private void Start()
   {
      Invoke("DelayFunc", persistTime);
   }
   ```

Timer: timer pause, timer reset, timer start method, timer method, timer end method, fixed interval call method. The timer can be set to be multiplexed or single.

Timer Manager (TimerMa): Its function is responsible for counting down and executing timer methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Object = System.Object;

 public class Timer
{
public delegate void IntervalAct(Object args);
//Total time and current duration
private float curtime = 0;
private float totalTime = 0;

//activation
public bool isActive;
//Whether the timer is destroyed
public bool isDestroy;
//whether to pause
public bool isPause;

//Interval events and interval events - Dot
private float intervalTime = 0;
private float curInterval = 0;
private IntervalAct onInterval;
private Object args;

// enter event
public Action onEnter;
private bool isOnEnter = false;
// persistent event
public Action onStay;
// exit event
public Action onEnd;

public Timer(float totalTime, bool isDestroy = true, bool isPause = false)
{
    curtime = 0;
    this.totalTime = totalTime;
    isActive = true;
    this.isDestroy = isDestroy;
    this.isPause = isPause;
    TimerMa.I.AddTimer(this);
}

public void Run()
{
    //pause timing
    if (isPause || !isActive)
        return;

    if (onEnter != null)
    {
        if (!isOnEnter)
        {
            isOnEnter = true;
            onEnter();
        }
    }

    // persistent event
    if (onStay != null)
        onStay();
    
    curtime += Time.deltaTime;

    //interval event
    if (onInterval != null)
    {
        curInterval += Time.deltaTime;
        if (curInterval > intervalTime)
        {
            onInterval(args);
            curInterval = 0;
        }
    }

    // timer ends
    if (curtime > totalTime)
    {
        curtime = 0;
        isActive = false;
        if (onEnd != null)
        {
            onEnd();
        }
    }
}

// set interval event
public void SetInterval(float interval, IntervalAct intervalFunc, Object args = null)
{
    this.intervalTime = interval;
    onInterval = intervalFunc;
    curInterval = 0;
    this.args = args;
}

// reset the timer
public void Reset()
{
    curtime = 0;
    isActive = true;
    isPause = false;
    curInterval = 0;
    isOnEnter = false;
}

//get the remaining time
public float GetRemainTime()
{
    return totalTime - curtime;
 }
 }
```

Timing Manager Code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class TimerMa : MonoBehaviour
{
 #region singleton

 private static TimerMa instance;
 TimerMa() {}

 public static TimerMa I
 {
     get
     {
         if (instance == null)
             instance = new TimerMa();
         return instance;
     }
 }

 #endregion
 private List<Timer> timerList;

 private void Awake()
 {
     instance = this;
     timerList = new List<Timer>();
 }

 public void AddTimer(Timer t)
 {
     timerList.Add(t);
 }

 void Update()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < timerList.Count;)
     {
         timerList[i].Run();
        
         //The timer is over and needs to be destroyed
         if(!timerList[i].isActive && timerList[i].isDestroy)
             timerList.RemoveAt(i);
         else
             ++i;
     }
 }
}
```

Test timer:

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.UI;
  using Object = System.Object;

  public class Test : MonoBehaviour
 {
    public Text mText1;
    public Text mText2;
    private Timer timer;
    private int count = 0;

void Start()
{
    timer = new Timer(5f,false);
    timer.SetInterval(1f, OnInterval);
    timer.onEnter = OnStart;
    timer.onEnd = OnExit;
}

void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(count);
    mText1.text = timer.GetRemainTime().ToString("f2");

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if (!timer.isPause)
        {
            timer.isPause = true;
            mText2.text = "Pause timer";
        }
    }
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        if (timer.isPause)
        {
            timer.isPause = false;
            mText2.text = "Cancel Pause Timer";
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        timer.Reset();
        mText2.text = "Reset timer";
    }
}

private void OnStart()
{
    mText2.text = "Start timing";
}

private void OnExit()
{
    mText2.text = "End timer";
}

 private void OnInterval(Object value)
 {
    count++;
    mText2.text = $"Interval event call {count}";
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just a question how could I check the time and date example being if the time was 2:00 pm on July 24th than the script will do something